# How to handle empty LHS in Mergerly

Tags: angular, codemirror

Hey I am using angular 5 and mergely to compare two diff. If both lhs and rhs contains the data then every thing is working fine but if one is empty and other contain thousands of line its trying to map one empty line to all those thousands and resulting in browser hanging.

```
Codepen Mergely example
```

https://codepen.io/Sphinxxxx/pen/grVvjG

But if I am replacing line no 24-26 by empty string its still matching empty string to everything in right side. Please help to fix this.

```
Jsfiddle Mergely example with lhs as null.
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8vdhra6m/

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on how many "thousands" of lines you have.  Normally, the algorithm for markup will mark all lines.  In this case, all the lines on the RHS are added.  I don't see anything out of the ordinary in your example code in jsfiddle.  I can only suggest that maybe you try enabling [viewport](http://www.mergely.com/doc#viewport), which can give a performance gain for many thousands of lines.